# Several tag wiki edits - How to review the older one?

Tags: support, review-queues

During a review, I came across a tag wiki edit twice. First I have approved the one which seemed to be the newer one with more text. Now there is a second one with less text, probably an earlier version of the same tag and same author as far as I can remember.

How shall this be reviewed?

URL to the second suggested edit (if that's still helpful). I didn't copy the first one, because I didn't know this would happen:

For now, I skipped it.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6596076

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite common when reviewing tag wiki edits. When editing, you are able to suggest edits to *both* the tag wiki and its excerpt at the same time. When they don't yet exist, the excerpt is oftentimes just copied into the tag wiki (or opposite), resulting in two suggestions that appear to be the same, but are actually for different posts.

This user did this very thing. He [suggested an edit to the xsuperobject tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6596075), and subsequently copied the first paragraph to the excerpt which created a second [suggested edit for the xsuperobject tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6596076).

It should be noted that it is not possible for two edits to be in the queue *for the same exact post*, which includes tag wikis. You will only ever encounter a tag wiki + excerpt pair in the review queue, which are treated as separate posts (one for the wiki, one for excerpt) by the system.